# Creating an operator to insert a custom pair into a custom set C++?

Tags: c++, operators

I have defined in my library:

```
using PointPair = std::pair<Point, Point>;
using PointPairSet = set<PointPair>;
```

I would like to do something like:

```
PointPairSet set;
set.insert(PointPair());
```

I tried to define the following operator:

```
friend bool operator<(const PointPair &pair) {
   return this.insert(pair);
}
```

But my knowledge of operators is essentially non-existant and this isn't working.

Comment: But why? Operator *less-than* is certainly not an obvious choice for *insertion* operation and will confuse readers. Why wouldn't you just call `insert()` method?

Comment: Read that https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators to improve your knowledge of operators.

Comment: _"this isn't working"_ tells us no more than "I have a problem". Note that asking your question in the first place already told us you have a problem. **How** is it not working? What are the symptoms?